# How can I get a list of all variables used in a template?

Tags: javascript, nunjucks

I have a situation when there are many templates that are using different variables. **How can get a list of all the variable names within one template**, so I could pass in exactly what the template needs when rendering?

I know I can use regular expression, but it's not as easy to implement as it may seem. The syntax around the variable name can really differ and I don't have the time or resources to lookup every possible situation.

Comment: Aren't nunchucks template variables enclosed by `{{ name }}`? If you want to capture that yet exclude everything that's, say, a function call, thta's relatively simple. What do your template variable names actually look like?

Comment: That's right. But the variable will not always perfectly appear like so `{{ name }}`. It might be `{{ name.child.grandchild }}`, `{{ name["child"] }}` or `{{ name[i] }}` and many more different expressions. I need to know what should be the property names of the `context` object that i pass in when rendering.

Comment: Yeah, but if we know that what appears inside `{{ }}` is always a candidate, and that the few that are _not_ candidates are function calls (which contain `()`) we can create a regex to look for all `{{}}` that don't have `()` within them. Or is that not capturing enough?

Comment: Well, if there is an expression `{{ name.child.grandchild }}` I need only the `name` part extracted. Also for loops are enclosed like `{% for item in items %}` and if statements `{% if variable %}`. So instead of regexp maybe there's a way to make use of the nunjucks parser?

Answer (score 1):

A regex would still work, given the following minimal test cases:

```
{{ name }}
{{ name.child }}
{{ name[child] }}
{{ name["child"] }}
{{ name_last["child"] }}
{{ name1["child"] }}
{{ function() }}
{% if variable %}
```

So, if you wanted to parse this as a pcre (*even though* the question is tagged [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) my understanding is that you want to pre-parse the page), you:

- Look for an opening `{{` and a closing `}}`, optionally padded by whitespace: `{{\s?\s?}}`
- Look for the 'head' of a context phrase: `([\w]+)`
- Create a second non-capture group with the stuff that delineates property selectors: `((?:\..+)|(?:\[.+))?`

And you're left with: `{{\s?([\w]+)((?:\..+)|(?:\[.+)?)\s?}}` whose first capture group (`$1`) which will match, in the test sample, `name`, `name_last` and `name1`.

[Live example](https://regex101.com/r/ffogTT/1).